# mod_ajp_proxy configurations and session stickiness

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache2, jboss5.x, mod-proxy

All,

I have a jboss and apache setup hosting my .war file. I have enabled session stickiness to forward requests from apache to jboss . Assume i have 2 apache and 2 jboss instances.

Is the below setting correct ? Currently session stickyness is not working and each time request is appended with a new JSESSSION ID.

```
     <Proxy balancer://cluster>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    BalancerMember ajp://1.1.1.1:8010/testing keepalive=On loadfactor=1 ping=10 ttl=600
    BalancerMember ajp://2.2.2.2:8010/testing keepalive=On loadfactor=1 ping=10 ttl=600
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /testing balancer://cluster timeout=60 stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=On
```

Do i need to add route variable to the balancer member configuration ??? and do i need to enable useJK flag in jboss.

Answer (score 0):

YES, you need to add route to each balancer member.

route=member1

route=member2

That is how Apache knows which way to direct later requests. Look at your cookies in your browser.